# Installing and Configuring DHCP server on Ubuntu 16.04 VPS from OVH

Tags: networking, server, vpn, dhcp, configure

I rented a VPS from OVH to make a VPN Server on it using SoftEther. Everything works fine when I do this at home on a VirtualBox machine. When I went over to the VPS....I didn't know how to properly configure the DHCP Server. When client PCs wanted to connect to the server it generates an error 720 and the connection stops on "Adding User to the network". That happens because my VPS can't assign local IPs to the subnet or the subnet doesn't exist at all. I tried to configure the DHCP server but with no luck.
My **ifconfig**:

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:f9:33:d8
          inet addr:51.254.125.169  Bcast:51.254.125.169  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fef9:33d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:178348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:140519 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:157509776 (157.5 MB)  TX bytes:15429200 (15.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1786 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:11700805 (11.7 MB)  TX bytes:11700805 (11.7 MB)
```

I really don't know how to go around this. Also here is the **/etc/network/interfaces/** file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg
```

I tried **route -n** and I got following results:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         51.254.120.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
51.254.120.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ens3
```

Maybe DHCP isn't the solution maybe iptables or something I don't know. Please help me out because the people from OVH aren't.

Comment: I'd setup Dnsmasq for as simple test I'm on my cell or I'd post a howto